# Conflict between Cassandra and Gatling

Tags: scala, cassandra, gatling

I´m start using gatling with this maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But I´m having then problems with my Cassandra component that use this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

When I see the logs I can see this exception

```
INFO  2017-04-25T14:31:43,119 []                                       [com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility] Detected Guava < 19 in the classpath, using legacy compatibility layer
INFO  2017-04-25T14:31:44,000 []                                       [com.datastax.driver.core.Native] Could not load JNR C Library, native system calls through this library will not be available (set this logger level to DEBUG to see the full stack trace).
INFO  2017-04-25T14:31:44,000 []                                       [com.datastax.driver.core.ClockFactory] Using java.lang.System clock to generate timestamps.
WARN  2017-04-25T14:31:44,789 []                                       [com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil] Found Netty's native epoll transport, but not running on linux-based operating system. Using NIO instead.
WARN  2017-04-25T14:31:46,457 []                                       [io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise] An exception was thrown by com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete()
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup.add(DefaultChannelGroup.java:146) ~[netty-transport-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup.add(DefaultChannelGroup.java:42) ~[netty-transport-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:161) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.2.0.jar:?]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:148) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.2.0.jar:?]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514) [netty-common-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:488) [netty-common-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$000(DefaultPromise.java:34) [netty-common-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:438) [netty-common-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor$TaskRunner.run(GlobalEventExecutor.java:233) [netty-common-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144) [netty-common-4.1.5.Final.jar:4.1.5.Final]
```

Any idea how to fix this conflict?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the conflict is that gatling requires netty 4.1 and the driver requires netty 4.0.  You can resolve this by using the shaded version of the driver and excluding the netty dependency explicitly from the driver.   From the [docs page](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/shaded_jar/):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <classifier>shaded</classifier>
    <!-- Because the shaded JAR uses the original POM, you still need
        to exclude this dependency explicitly: -->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Works pretty good! I was trying to exclude one particular artifactId of netty, but seems the problem was another. With * works just fine!!

Comment: Anny idea why it´s workinf in Windows system, but in Linux still failing?

Comment: Is the exception different?

Comment: I thought that was working but I´m afraid still not. Adding your dependency config I receive now java.lang.AbstractMethodError. Tomorrow I can post you the stacktrace. Bufff this is madness

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue in our project some time ago. After investigation we found conflicting netty versions.
Adding the shaded netty jar to datastax driver dependecny led to issues on Linux sytems, because in this case the shaded netty jar does not use Native epoll transport on Linux systems.
We just removed `shaded` classifier from datastax driver dependency, but add exclusion for netty:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2</version>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

It works on both Linux and Windows systems. But we were lucky and our netty version is compatible with the datastax driver version.